# Probability that $\sum_n T_n<\infty$, arrival time.

Tags: probability

I am reading a probability book, and there is something I don't understand.

Suppose that customers arrive at times $T_1;T_1+T_2;\ldots;T_1+\ldots T_n;\ldots$ (independent strictly positive random variables)

Let $Y_n$ be the arrival time of the $n-$th customer that is $Y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n T_k.$ Now, let $Z_t$ be the waiting time for $t\ge 0.$

The book said:

> if $Z_t\le x$ then some customer arrives in $(t,t+x]$ and hence a.e. there is a last customers to arrive in this interval. (If not, then $\sum_n T_n<\infty$ and this has probability zero by strong law of large numbers)

I don't understand why this follow from the strong law of large numbers ? Isn't the Kolmogorov zero-one law ? But still it can be probability one, isn't it ?

Comment: You say $Z_t$ is the waiting time for $t\geq 0$. What does that  mean? The waiting time of what?

Comment: Waiting time from t to the arrival of the next customer @AlexR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what it's saying is that you can't have infinitely many customers arrive in a finite interval. The proof is that, if there really were infinitely many customers arriving in a finite interval of time, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n<\infty$. This is impossible because the SLLN implies that:

$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N T_n}{N}\rightarrow E[T_1]>0,$$

and this would be impossible since if the numerator stays bounded, the fraction would go to 0.

Comment: I still don't understand where is the contradiction in the SLLN ?

Comment: "and this would be impossible since if the numerator stays bounded, the fraction would go to 0."